# React Native - Image Cache

Tags: react-native

I read the document about the React Native image component in this site and got some questions: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html

1. If I use the source property to display image. Will the image be cached and save to disk after download?
2. If yes, what is the cache policy?
3. If I want to save the downloaded image to disk. Is it better to use getSize or prefetch method to do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: I hope it'll help you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58799748/9908240

Answer (score 4):

React native image component NSURLRequest's cache policy as described [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7571). Personally I use RNFetchBlob to cache images as described [here](https://medium.com/@wcandillon/image-caching-in-react-native-96d8df33ca84). You can also checkout [this component](https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-img-cache).

Answer (score 3):

FastImage is best for Image Cache

yarn add react-native-fast-image

Ref: https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

Its maximum props behave like as React native image attribute

```js
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'


<FastImage
    style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
    source={{ uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1' }}
    resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.stretch}

/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in my higher order component module that adds performance related image caching and "permanent cache" functionality to the native <Image> component.

[React Native Image Cache HOC](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-image-cache-hoc)

Tl;DR Code Example:

```js
import imageCacheHoc from 'react-native-image-cache-hoc';
const CacheableImage = imageCacheHoc(Image);

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <CacheableImage style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://i.redd.it/rc29s4bz61uz.png'}} />
        <CacheableImage style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://i.redd.it/hhhim0kc5swz.jpg'}} permanent={true} />
      </View>
  );
  }
}
```

The first image will be cached until the total local cache grows past 15 MB (by default) then cached images are deleted oldest first until total cache is below 15 MB again.

The second image will be stored to local disk permanently. People use this as a drop in replacement for shipping static image files with your app.

That should handle your requirement out of the box. Hope it helps!

Comment: hi, if I use `<CacheableImage style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://i.redd.it/hhhim0kc5swz.jpg'}} permanent={true} />` and save the images, and next I disconnect the network. the images will show if I use `<CacheableImage style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'https://i.redd.it/hhhim0kc5swz.jpg'}} permanent={true} />`?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo Yes. The image file is saved to local disk, and so long as the permanent prop is set to true, the local file will never be deleted (and if a file exists locally, CacheableImage uses that first instead of hitting the network). If you don't set the permanent prop to true, the local file could be deleted from local cache and then the network would be hit again to pull down the remote image file again.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo Also, instead of using the component to render once and download the file to local disk initially, you can use the CacheableImage.cacheFile() static method (https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-image-cache-hoc#static-methods) to download the remote image to local disk programmatically. I'd also suggest using my queue (https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-queue) if you plan on downloading a ton of images programmatically.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo If you need to cache a json response, I would store it using AsyncStorage.

AsyncStorage.setItem('cacheKey', '{"exampleJson":2}');

Then pull the cache out later via:

const jsonCache = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cacheKey');

More info: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: For advanced data storage, use redux and redux-persist.

Answer (score 1):

#### Process

React Native does cache images after downloading and decoding them.
[image]

#### Cache policy

1. expiration time

[image]

2.using Bitmap size as cache cost; by default, total 20MB cache capacity in React Native iOS

3. unknown storage and eviction policy in `NSCache` in iOS

see more in [How Image Loader and Cache work in React Native under the hood](http://%20https://suelan.github.io/2020/12/24/20201224-How-Image-Loader-and-Cache-work-in-React-Native/)