# React native Loading image and store in Device?

Tags: android, ios, image, react-native, native

I am Creating react native application for both ios and android
In the application, there is a lot of images and gifs which increase the size of the app
to solve the problem I uploaded the image to the server and loading from the server
**But the issue is that I don't want each time user opens the app to load images instead i need to store them in local storage and read from there if an image is not available on local storage then it will download and store there. Need the best way to do this in react native **
React native version 0.64

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/58799482/3098008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you make the api call to fetch the images from the server, if you are using AsyncStorage, check if the images are stored in AsyncStorage

```
const loadLocalImages = async() => {
    try {
      const images = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@images_Key');
           if(images !== null) {
               //set your variables
            }else {
               //fetch images from api
             }
       }cache(e){
          //log error if any
       }
 }
```

Comment: This worked fine but async storage had a memory limitation of 6MB - 10MB

Comment: You can choose to use React native realm to store your images, here is the link to the documentation 
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/